# How does the Windows HID attribute IOCTLs work in Windows?

Tags: driver, hid, ioctl, wdm

I am reverse engineering a driver that implements HID for the purposes of searching for vulnerabilities.

The main IOCTLs it implements are all from the HID minidriver libraries in the WDK.

I am in particular interested in sending malformed values to the IOCTL_HID_SET_FEATURE IOCTL. However, based on Microsoft's documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/hidclass/ni-hidclass-ioctl_hid_set_feature

It is somewhat unclear as to how I would set a feature for one particular HID device as opposed to any other from the documentation. It is a little hand wavy as to what is expected to be in a feature report.

> The input buffer size, in bytes, must be large enough to hold the feature report -- excluding its report >ID, if report IDs are used - plus one additional byte that specifies a nonzero report ID or zero.

> The Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer member points to the input buffer that contains a feature report. If >the collection includes report IDs, the requester must set the first byte of the buffer to a nonzero >report ID; otherwise the requester must set the first byte to zero. The feature report -- excluding its >report ID, if report IDs are used - is located at ((PUCHAR)ReportBuffer + 1).

The documentation refers to the IOCTL as targeting a "top-level collection." but based on my reading of my own driver's disassembly it looks like you can specify features on a granular level, specific to an individual device.

Two interrelated questions here:

1. Is it possible to target these IOCTLs toward a specific device rather than a class of devices? If so how? If you can point me toward an example of a client that does this, that would be awesome.
2. What specifically is in a HID feature report/where can I find a spec that defines it?

Comment: Can't tell for the 1st part of your question; as for the 2nd question it is clear, from the WDK samples that a HID report is **developer-defined** since it is related to the underlying hardware. [This line](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/hid/hidusbfx2/sys/hid.c#L314) from a MS HID sample tells it clearly. Happy hunting ;)

Comment: I'm surprised that there isn't a standard format. I'll keep searching for the first question.